# iAdBannerView_problem

Tags: iphone, iad, ipad, universal, banner

My application is Universal app and i am implementing iAd in this app, Just wanted to know that what is the height and width of the iad banner view for iphone and ipad. I am doing through Xib, when i place the iad banner view in the xib the height sometimes increases or decreases, So i am not able to get what should i keep the height of the iad banner view. Please suggest me some solutions regarding this as i need to put this application in app store very soon.

Please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iphone its height is 50 for potrait and 32 for landscape For ipad its height is 66 for potrait and 66 for landscape

Answer (score 0):

Adding from interface builder can be problematic....This is the best tutorial for adding iAds.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

It caters to the following:

1. Hiding iAd if no add is available.
2. resizing on interface orientation.

You can add same code to both iphone and ipad view controllers just change the values of the size constants (ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 etc)

Comment: thanks but i wanted it to add through xib 
nyways i got the answer
For iphone its height is 50 for potrait and 32 for landscape
For ipad its height is 66 for potrait and 66 for landscape

Comment: if your app is targetted fro iOS 4.0 and later, only then adding from xib would be a good choice otherwise ur app will crash on earlier osz

Answer (score 0):

I found this one has explained the step by step [implementation of iAds...](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/tag/iad)